# Error with Withdrawing Ethereum into Account

Tags: remix, blockchain, ether, metamask, wallets

I am attempting to withdraw ETH from my smart contract that I have deployed using Solidity in Remix. I have already deposited 0.001 ETH into the smart contract using MetaMask and wish to use the withdraw function I created in Solidity to withdraw that 0.001 ETH into my Ether Wallet. However, whenever I click on the withdraw button (and specify that I wish to withdraw 0.001 ETH) in remix, the block explorer shows that I did not withdraw anything. Any guesses why?

Please let me know if you need additional details.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please, provide contract source code as text. It makes testing much easier.

Comment: Were you able to transfer your eth to Metamask?
Because I also have Eth in a smartcontract but the withdrawal option doesnt work properly.
Could you send me the code you used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `withdraw_amount` should be in wei. Because you have put withdraw amount 1 and you are dividing it by 1000 in uint256 division 1/1000 is 0.

You have to pass `withdraw_amountt` in wei like

```
1000000000000000000 = 1 ether
1000000000000000000/1000 = 10000000000000000 = 0.001 ether
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The wei computation is indeed correct. I tried your method and the withdrawal amount goes to 0.001 ether, but on (https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xd618179807f9c30a3927ada47fb7c23b83b4defa5cde863cef32165bba51a9cd) it shows a contract value of zero, which does not make sense. Any ideas? My wallet balance also shows no funds being withdrawn successfully

Comment: The ETH withdrawn from any contract is in the record under internal transaction in etherscan. You can check the incoming ETH amounts in your wallet in internal transaction tab. 
https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x0ccabcef9d0d14c555e429fbc721e0ed561e0393#internaltx

Comment: Thank you so much! I wish I could upvote your comment because I have been cracking my head for so long over this. How long does it usually take for the ETH to come into your account?

Comment: As long as the transaction is complete